# Find the complex number $p+qi$.

Tags: complex-numbers

$a, b, c$ are different complex numbers and they satisfy the following:

$$\frac{a}{1-b}=\frac{b}{1-c}=\frac{c}{1-a}=p+qi.$$

Find the values for $p$ and $ q$.

I have found out that $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0$

Comment: Your last post is also a problem-statement question. What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $p+qi = z$, then $ z =  a + zb = b + z c = c + za $.

By taking the difference of these equations, show that $ z^3 =-1$, .

If $ z = -1$, then prove that there are no solutions.
If $ z = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$, then find solutions.
If $ z = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$, then find solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. What do you mean when you say 'taking the difference?' Since I am not a native English speaker, I don't know what that means.

Comment: $a-b=z(c-b)$. More work is needed, so if you want more help, show your work and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: I solved it. Thank you so much. Have a nice day.